# Can I show that this function is surjective?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

$$f(x+f(x))+f(x-f(x))=x$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can I conclude that $f$ is *surjective*? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to believe in yourself. You can do anything you set your mind to.

Comment: It takes justification.  I think you will find that $f(x)$ is surjective, but it is not automatic.  As the right can range over all of $\Bbb R$, the left has to do so, as well.

Comment: @OpenBall While the titel says *assume*, the body says *conclude*. And for that it is not sufficient to set one's mind to something.

Comment: He might have been sarcastic.

Comment: No, you can't assume it.  You have to prove it.

Comment: Okay, I was utterly confused with assume in the title and conclude in the body.  Do please clear that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all $x \in \Bbb R$, there exist real numbers $a = x + f(x)$ and $b = x - f(x)$ such that 
$$
x = f(a) + f(b)
$$
Let $S$ denote $f(\Bbb R)$, i.e. the image of $f$.  It's clear that $\{c + d : c,d \in S\} = \Bbb R$ (more concisely, $S + S = \Bbb R$).

If we know that $f$ is continuous, then the above allows us to conclude that $f$ is surjective.  In particular, it suffices to state that because $S + S$ is not bounded above and not bounded below, $S$ is also not bounded above and not bounded below.  Because $S= f(\Bbb R)$ is also connected, we can conclude that $f(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R$.

If we are to answer this without the assumption of continuity, things get tricky.  In order for $f$ to fail to be surjective, $S$ would need to be such that $S + S = \Bbb R$ with $S \neq \Bbb R$.  It is not obvious to me that this should be possible without invoking the axiom of choice.  Even if we could find such an $S$, it is unclear how one could get $f$ to actually satisfy the functional equation.

Comment: An interesting observation is that $f(x) = 0 \implies x = 0$.